# from x per 100 person-years to x per 100,000 person-years?

Tags: biostatistics, epidemiology

If something is reported in per 100 person-years, like in the below table, is it possible for me to convert it into per 100,000 person-years simply by multiplying by 1,000?

That is, 2.21 per 100 person-years can be converted to 2,210 per 100,000 person-years?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use the values as you've stated because that is what "per 100 person-years" implies: your measure is a rate, and you can answer questions like "how many incidence can I expect in 100000 years?"

The confidence interval on the other hand depends on the underlying probabilistic model. Yours doesn't look like its Gaussian so its not obvious how it'll change but generally if you scale a random variable by a constant you get $E[aX]=aE[X]$ but $Var[aX]=a^2Var[X]$ so you wouldn't expect the errors to scale linearly even in the Gaussian case. I.e. you can't just multiply the lower and upper bounds.